# How do I start a service on boot in debian?

Tags: linux, shell, service, debian, boot

So I created a service and made it executale in /etc/init.d
Then I tried to make it start after boot with the following command:

```
update-rc.d <myService> defaults
```

But the output were warnings of other services (which work just fine by the way) and I don't want to touch those.

My next attempt to solve this was to add the following lines in the rc.local file:

```
do_start() {
        service <someOtherService> stop
        service <myService> stop
        sleep 5
        service <someOtherService> start
        service <myService> stop
        ........
```

As I said, I have some other service that works just fine, but my service which I am currently trying to add wont start after boot.

One more thing that I would like to add is when I manually enter:

```
service <myService> start/stop
```

then it works just fine

Answer (score 4):

The following works very well for me.

First determine if your system is running SysV **init or systemd**, for that use:

```
$ ps -p 1
```

If SysV **init**:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d <service_name> defaults 95 10
```

If **systemd**:

```
$ sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo /bin/systemctl enable <service_name>.service
```

I successfully used the last one on a ParrotSecurity OS that is based on Debian 5.

Answer (score 1):

To add a service at boot, you can add an Upstart job.

Create your conf file in /etc/init (e.g. /etc/init/myjob.conf)

with a content like this (Example)

```
description "My job"
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/script.sh
```

More informations [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Upstart) (Debian doc)

Info: you need the upstart package.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Does this goes hand in hand with service or should I completely remove the functioning service I created in favor of upstart?

Comment: Well, sorry about that, I'm not an expert, but it seems like it's replacing the systemd service for startup.